# Promise not being executed in Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, es6-promise

I'm currently creating a new React component for one of our projects and I'm pretty much stuck with writing a proper test for it. I've read quite a few docs and blog posts and more but I can't seem to get it running.

### TL;DR

To me, it seems the Promise is not executed. When I run the test with a debugger, it won't stop in the Promise's function and neither in the then() function. It will, however, stop in the then/catch functions in the test itself.

### The Code

So, the component is actually fairly simple. For the time being it is supposed to search for a location via an API. The test for it looks like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import {shallowWithIntl} from "../../../Helpers/react-intl-helper";
import Foo from "../../../../src/Components/Foo/Foo";
import {mount} from "enzyme";

const queryTerm = 'exampleQueryTerm';
const locationAgs = 'exampleLocationKey';

const fakeLocationObject = {
  search: '?for=' + queryTerm + '&in=' + locationAgs
};

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  const exampleLocations = [{
    data: {"id": "expected-location-id"}
  }];

  return {
    get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(exampleLocations)
    })
  };
});

let fooWrapper, instance;

beforeEach(() => {
  global.settings = {
    "some-setting-key": "some-setting-value"
  };

  global.URLSearchParams = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      get: function(param) {
        if (param === 'for') return queryTerm;
        else if (param === 'in') return locationAgs;
        return '';
      }
    }
  });

  fooWrapper = shallowWithIntl(<Foo location={fakeLocationObject} settings={ global.settings } />).dive();
  instance = fooWrapper.instance();
});

it('loads location and starts result search', function() {
  expect.assertions(1);

  return instance
    .searchLocation()
    .then((data) => {
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).not.toBeNull();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).toBe(error);
    });
});
```

So, as you can see the test is supposed to call `searchLocation` on the Foo component instance, which returns a Promise object, as you can (almost) see in its implementation.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";
import {searchLocationByKey} from "../../Services/Vsm";

class Foo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      location: null,
      searchingLocation: false,
      searchParams: new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search)
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.settings && this.props.settings) {
      this.searchLocation();
    }
  }

  searchLocation() {
    this.setState({
      searchingLocation: true
    });

    const key = this.state.searchParams.get('in');

    return searchLocationByKey(key)
      .then(locations => {
        this.setState({ location: locations[0], searchingLocation: false })
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    // Renders something
  };

}

export default injectIntl(Foo);
```

Enter `searchLocationByKey`:

```js
function requestLocation(url, resolve, reject) {
  axios.get(url).then(response => {
    let locations = response.data.map(
      location => ({
        id: location.collectionKey || location.value,
        rs: location.rs,
        label: location.label,
        searchable: location.isSearchable,
        rawData: location
      })
    );

    resolve(locations);
  }).catch(error => reject(error));
}

export const searchLocationByKey = function(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let url = someGlobalBaseUrl + '?regional_key=' + encodeURIComponent(key);
    requestLocation(url, resolve, reject);
  });
};
```

### The Problem

This is the output of the test:

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  [Error: expect(received).not.toBeNull()

Expected value not to be null, instead received
  null]
Received:
  null
```

I have to admit that I'm pretty new to Promises, React and JavaScript testing, so I might have mixed up several things. As I wrote above, it seems that the Promise is not executed properly. When debugging, it will not stop in the then() function defined in `Foo.searchLocation`. Instead, apparently, both the then() and catch() functions defined in the test are executed.

I've spent way too much time on this issue already and I'm clueless on how to go on. What am I doing wrong?

### Update 1: done() function

As El Aoutar Hamza pointed out in an answer below, it is possible to pass a function (usually called "done") to the test function. I've done exactly this:

```js
it('loads location and starts result search', function(done) {
  expect.assertions(1);

  return instance
    .searchLocation()
    .then((data) => {
      expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).not.toBeNull();
      done();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).toBe(error);
    });
});
```

But I end up getting this error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like I mentioned in my latest comment under El Aoutar Hamza's answer, I have found a solution thanks to a colleague who was able to help me.

It seems that it is not possible to return the Promise from `Foo.searchLocation` on to the test. What we needed to do was to wrap the code getting and handling the Promise from `searchLocationByKey` into yet another Promise, which looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl";
import {searchLocationByKey} from "../../Services/Vsm";

class Foo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      location: null,
      searchingLocation: false,
      searchParams: new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search)
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.settings && this.props.settings) {
      this.searchLocation();
    }
  }

  searchLocation() {
    this.setState({
      searchingLocation: true
    });

    const key = this.state.searchParams.get('in');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      searchLocationByKey(key)
        .then(locations => {
          this.setState({ location: locations[0], searchingLocation: false });
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error));
          reject();
        }
    });
  }

  render() {
    // Renders something
  };

}

export default injectIntl(Foo);
```

Only then was Jest able to properly hook into the promise and everything worked as I expected it to be in the first place.

I still didn't understand why the promise cannot simply be returned and needs to be wrapped in another Promise, though. So if someone has an explanation for that it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `requestLocation`  you are trying to access `response.data`, and when mocking `axios.get`, you are returning a Promise resolved with an **array** ! you should instead return a Promise resolved with an **object** with `data` property (that contains the array).

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    data: [{ "id": "expected-location-id" }]
   }))
}));
```

Another point is that when testing asynchronous code, the test will finish before even calling the callbacks, that's why you should consider providing your test an argument called [done](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html), that way, jest will wait until the done callback is called.

```
describe('Foo', () => {
    it('loads location and starts result search', done => {
      expect.assertions(1);

      return instance
        .searchLocation()
        .then((data) => {
          expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).not.toBeNull();
          done();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          expect(fooWrapper.state('location')).toBe(error);
          done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Indeed, the return value was wrong. I've tried the done function as well and it didn't really work out, but resulted in this error:

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: When you passe an argument (`done`) to `it` you need to call it inside your test to let Jasmine knows that your test is done, i.e you need to call it inside your promise handler

Comment: I did exactly that. I've updated my post with the results.

Comment: You are not calling it in `catch` as well, and it seems that you didn't fix what I said about mocking `axios.get` (I edited my answer)

Comment: I've tried to call it in both branches as well, but the result was the same. I've adapted the mocking but didn't copy it into the post, sorry. :) In the meantime, I was able to get it working with a colleague. Will post an answer.